# creating valid test SSL certificates for IIS

Tags: wcf, powershell, ssl, iis, certificate

I want to test SSL connections in an development environment with IIS. For this i need to crate a self-signed root certificate that gets installed in the machine store, and also another certificate that gets signed with the root certificate to install in IIS.

Doing it with `makecert` is deprecated now, so I am wondering how to do it with Powershell and the `New-SelfSignedCertificate` command.

Bonus points if you get the key usage settings right :-)

Note: using the self-signed certificated directly in IIS does not work, since the browser and WCF considers them invalid.

---

for reference, here is how to do it with makecert:

```
# create the self signed root certificate 
makecert -n "CN=root.lan" -r -sv root.pvk root.cer

# create the certificate for IIS that gets signed with the root certificate 
makecert -sk "Local Certificate" -iv root.pvk -n "CN=localhost" -ic root.cer -sr localmachine -ss my -sky exchange -pe

# convert to other formats 
cert2spc localhost.cer localhost.spc
pvk2pfx -pvk localhost.pvk -spc localhost.spc -pfx localhost.pfx
```

Comment: `MakeCert.exe` is enough if you use RSA only keys, but it's better to use some additional options of `MakeCert.exe`. `New-SelfSignedCertificate` will get you no advantages. Other Powershell modules available on internet could be better. You can use [OpenSSL.exe](https://www.openssl.org/) instead `MakeCert.exe` to create either RSA or Elliptic Curve certificates, which you can use on IIS. If your IIS server is available over Internet (port 80) then you could use Let's Encrypt to get for free real SSL certificate and the clients will don't need to install your "CA" certificate in trusted root.

Comment: the question was to use `New-SelfSignedCertificate` for a reason. i don't want to use `MakeCert` or `OpenSSL`.

Comment: Just use start powershell and use `New-SelfSignedCertificate -?` and `get-help New-SelfSignedCertificate -examples`. The possibilities depends of Windows version, which you use. Compare https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848633.aspx with https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848633(v=wps.630).aspx

Comment: the operating system is Windows 10 in my case. an update of the powershell version should also enable newer features on older systems. 

I guess the `-ExistingKey` parameter might be the key to the solution (like the `-iv` paramter in `MakeCert`). however, I didn't find an example so far.

Comment: It seems to me that `-Signer` specify the CA certificate. I made some tests and will post my answer soon with examples of usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new version of `New-SelfSignedCertificate`, which included on Windows 10, is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps). One can use `New-SelfSignedCertificate -?` and `get-help New-SelfSignedCertificate -examples` to get some additional information.

The documentation and the examples could seems still not clear enough for creating two certificates:

- one self-signed certificate, which will be used as CA certificate from your example
- the second SSL certificate, which signed with the first certificate.

The implementation could be the following (I wrote below the option in multiple lines only to make the text more readable):

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -HashAlgorithm sha384 -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 4096
    -Subject "CN=My Test (PowerShell) Root Authority,O=OK soft GmbH,C=DE"
    -KeyUsage DigitalSignature,CertSign -NotAfter (get-date).AddYears(10)
    -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -Type Custom
```

the output will look like

```
    Directory: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::CurrentUser\My


Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
B7DE93CB88E99B01D166A986F7BF2D82A0E541FF  CN=My Test (PowerShell) Root Authority, O=OK soft GmbH, C=DE
```

The value `B7DE93CB88E99B01D166A986F7BF2D82A0E541FF` is important for usage the certificate for signing. If you forget the value you can find it by CN name

```
dir cert:\CurrentUser\My | where Subject -Like "CN=My Test (PowerShell)*"
```

or by usage `certutil.exe -user -store My` to display certificates on My store of the current user.

To create SSL certificate and to sign it with respect of previously created certificate one can do for example the following

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Subject "CN=ok01.no-ip.org"
    -HashAlgorithm sha256 -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048
    -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment,DigitalSignature
    -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
    -Signer cert:\CurrentUser\My\B7DE93CB88E99B01D166A986F7BF2D82A0E541FF
    -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2","2.5.29.17={text}DNS=ok01.no-ip.org&DNS=ok01.fritz.box")
```

It seems to me that the final certificate will have all properties required. It's clear that the values from many from above parameters contains examples only any you have to modify there based on your requirements. I don't describe here some other common steps like importing root certificate in Trusted Root, exporting the certificates and so on. The steps are not the psrt of your main question.

Comment: @MovGP0: You are welcome! I still recommend you to take a look in Let's Encrypt. Look at [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Feb/22/Using-Lets-Encrypt-with-IIS-on-Windows). I personally use [letsencrypt-win-simple](https://github.com/Lone-Coder/letsencrypt-win-simple) to create SSL certificate using Let's Encrypt authority which is trusted on all computers.

Comment: I needed to specify `-KeyUsage DigitalSignature,CertSign` for the CA cert, otherwise web browsers would not validate the 'child' certificate.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: Thank you! I changed the value of `-KeyUsage` parameter used to generate root certificate.